# Creating compressed tar file, with only subset of files, remotely over SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, tar

I've successfully managed to transfer a tar file over SSH on stdout from a remote system, creating a compressed file locally, by doing something like this:

```
read -s sudopass
ssh me@remote "echo $sudopass | sudo -S tar cf - '/dir'" 2>/dev/null | XZ_OPT='-6 -T0 -v' xz > dir.tar.xz
```

As expected this gets me a `dir.tar.xz` locally which is all of the remote `/dir` compressed.

I've also managed to figure out how to *locally* only compress a subset of files, by passing a filelist to `tar` with `-T` on STDIN:

```
find '/dir' -name '*.log' | XZ_OPT='-6 -T0 -v' tar cJvf /root/logs.txz -T -
```

My main question is: how would I go about doing the first thing (transfer plain tar remotly, then compress locally) while at the same time telling `tar` that I only want to do it on a specific subset of files?

When I try combining the two:

```
ssh me@remote "echo $sudopass | sudo -S find '/dir' -name '*.log' | tar cf
-T -" | XZ_OPT='-6 -T0 -v' xz > cypress_logs.tar.xz
```

I get errors like:

```
tar: -: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
```

I feel like `tar` isn't liking the fact that I'm both passing it something on STDIN as well as expecting it to output to STDOUT. Adding another `-` didn't seem to help either.

Also, as a bonus question, if anyone has a better idea on how to pass `$sudopass` above that would be great, since this method -- while avoiding having the password in the bash history -- makes the sudo password show up in the process list while it's running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the `f` option requires an argument, so when you write `cf -T -`, I suspect that the `-T` is getting consumed as the argument to `f`, which throws off the rest of the command line.

This works for me:

```
ssh me@remote "echo $password | sudo -S find /tmp/dir -name '*.log' | tar -cf- -T-"
```

You could also write it like this:

```
ssh me@remote "echo $password | sudo -S find /tmp/dir -name '*.log' | tar cf - -T-"
```

But I prefer to always use `-` for options, rather than legacy tar's weird options without any prefix.

Comment: wow, tar syntax really is some black magic. thanks!